# log4j2 configuration is loaded but not applied

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

log4j2 configuration is loaded but not applied.
below the Trace of log4j2 is initialized, log4j2 is Stopped for some reason and just atarted with no MBeans.( I don't know what it exactly is )

when I logged at some class, the configuration wasn't applied and they only show "Error" Level.

probably the Default config is applied for some reason. How can I solve this problem?

```
2022-06-22 11:45:10,043 main TRACE YamlConfiguration notified 9 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
2022-06-22 11:45:10,044 main TRACE YamlConfiguration stopping 8 LoggerConfigs.
2022-06-22 11:45:10,044 main TRACE YamlConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
2022-06-22 11:45:10,044 main TRACE YamlConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
2022-06-22 11:45:10,044 main TRACE YamlConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
2022-06-22 11:45:10,044 main DEBUG Appender Console_Appender stopped with status true
2022-06-22 11:45:10,044 main DEBUG Appender RollingFile_Appender stopped with status true
2022-06-22 11:45:10,044 main DEBUG Appender File_Appender stopped with status true
2022-06-22 11:45:10,044 main TRACE YamlConfiguration stopped 3 remaining Appenders.
2022-06-22 11:45:10,044 main TRACE YamlConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 9 LoggerConfigs.
2022-06-22 11:45:10,044 main DEBUG Stopped YamlConfiguration[location=/Users/[personal information]build/resources/main/log4j2.yml] OK
2022-06-22 11:45:10,044 main DEBUG JMX disabled for Log4j2. Not registering MBeans.
2022-06-22 11:45:10,044 main TRACE Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
2022-06-22 11:45:10,044 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=7c53a9eb, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@758a34ce] started OK with configuration YamlConfiguration[location=/Users...[personal information]
```

Comment: When using Spring Boot, Log4j2 is configured at least twice, the second configuration is performed programmatically by Spring Boot with a reduced discovery mechanism. Can you add the logs of both initializations and the version of Spring Boot and Log4j2?

Comment: I'm using springboot 2.6.8 and spring-boot-starter-log4j2. I excluded spring-boot-starter-logging. I have only one configuration which is log4j2.yml in my resource directory.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I tried debugging the configuration of Logger. the configuration file is properly referred but log level is changed "Debug" to "Error". I don't know why it is.